# C# - how to identify a every single button clicked from form 1 on form 3?

Tags: c#

I'm having a lot of troubles with this

I'm using 3 forms on visual studio, the first one (form 1) is a status screen with a lot of green buttons, each one representing a machine. Once you click one of the buttons it should open a basic login screen to verify you have rights to access to the next step (Form 2), and once you log in, there's another winform (Form 3) to generate a failure report. Once you submit the failure report, it should identify the clicked button on form 1 and change the color and text of the button.

The deal here is that i don't know how to identify the button, i have this code on form 3:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       foreach (Form1 f1 in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>())
        {
            f1.button1.Text = "your text here"; // Provided button1 is public.

        }
    }
```

If i leave the code this way, it will work only for the button1 of Form1. I want it to identify any clicked button

Answer (score 1):

`sender` is actually the `Button` that triggered the event.

After casting `sender` to `Button` you can access its various properties to do whatever you like,  e.g. check the `Button` name or change its text.

```
var button = sender as Button:
if (button.Name == "myButton1") {
   // do this and that for button 1
}
```

This answer is intended to answer your question directly, no comments on design which might be suboptimal.